# How to loop through each line of log file and building the values

Tags: c#

I have a big log file like this:

```
    2020-03-25 13:15:41 App initialized.
    2020-03-25 13:18:22.477 ERROR Exception from api  blah blah blah blah:  NOT FOUND
            at element(bl:97) ~[classes/:na]
            at blah blah blah blah(bm:997) ~[classes/:na]   
            at blah blah blah blah(yq:5) ~[classes/:na]
            at blah blah blah blah(Native Method) ~[na:1.4.0_111]   
    2020-03-25 13:18:22.477 ERROR blah blah - Exception from api  blah blah blah blah: STATUS MONITOR   
            at element(bl:97) ~[classes/:na]
            at blah blah blah blah(bm:997) ~[classes/:na]   
            at blah blah blah blah(yq:5) ~[classes/:na]
            at blah blah blah blah(Native Method) ~[na:1.4.0_111]
```

And need to write a function that will return the the time stamp and text from the errors.

```
2020-03-25 13:18:22.477
```

as the keys, and

```
ERROR Exception from api  blah blah blah blah:  NOT FOUND
            at element(bl:97) ~[classes/:na]2020-03-25 13:15:41  
            at blah blah blah blah(bm:997) ~[classes/:na]   
            at blah blah blah blah(yq:5) ~[classes/:na]
            at blah blah blah blah(Native Method) ~[na:1.4.0_111]
```

as the values

I am using a `Dictionary<DateTime, string>` to hold the data and a Stringbuilder to build each line of the error. But i cant figure out how to loop thrugh it correctly without compromising the data i am trying to build because it gets reset every line.

```
                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
                {
                    bool isTimeStamp = false;
                    do
                    {
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        timeStamp = new DateTime();
                        try
                        {
                            timeStamp = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 24));
                            isTimeStamp = true;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine(line);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    while (!isTimeStamp);

                    logs.Add(timeStamp, sb.ToString());
                }
```

Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use regular expressions. There's lots of information available on SO and elsewhere. A good place to start is here; https://regexr.com/. Good luck!

Comment: Using Regex in this case would end up with code that nobody would understand and would not be able to maintain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(?'date'[^\s]+\s[^\s]+)\s+(?'error'.*)";
            Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime,List<string>>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            List<string> messages = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("at"))
                    {
                        messages.Add(line.Trim());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
                        string dateStr = match.Groups["date"].Value;
                        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
                        string message = match.Groups["error"].Value.Trim();
                        messages = new List<string>();
                        messages.Add(message);
                        dict.Add(date, messages);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i will need some time to understand it and implement it into my program but it looks like it works